# visual studio can't find unit tests in web project

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I've created a bunch of unit tests for methods in my web project, but i can't make visual studio find these unit tests.

The unit tests are located in App_Code/Tests/testfile (there's multiple test files under the folder tests)

How do i make visual studio find these tests ?

I tried having a seperate unit test project at first, but i couldn't reference the web project, and therefore not call any of the methods in the .cs files under App_Code.

Answer (score 1):

Refactor the solution so that the code that you are testing is in one assembly for example Dataaccess.dll that is referenced from the web project and the test in a test project DataaccessTests that also reference the Dataaccess.dll project.

Comment: Does this mean that there is no way to define a folder with unit tests inside a webproject ?

Comment: I think the best practices is to separate test code and production code. A good reson to create a layered and modularized application is to be able to test the application. So if it is hard to reference the web project in the test project I would suggest layering the web application into components that can be isolated and tested is the way forward for you.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mathias.
It's a better design to modularize your code in layers.
So you create Assemblies for example for your Business logic and your Dataaccess Logic.
These are not webbased and are pretty easy to Test.
You can add References to this Assemblies and test them.
If you follow this approach you will have at least 3 Projects:

1. WebUi
2. BusinessLogic
3. Dataacces

The WebUi Projekt references the BusinessLogic project and the BusinessLogic project references the Dataaccess projekt.

In the WebUi Project only do UI related stuff and let the BusinessLogic Layer do the work.

Hope it helps...

Comment: we used this structure but it was troublesome when we wanted to save our connection in only one place, to avoid having to change it in several locations when deploying from out test enviroment to the "real" enviroment.
we might lack som basic knowledge about best practice here

Comment: Do you mean the Connection String? If yes, you need to add a configuration file (Web.Config) to the WebUi project. And only there. So you have just one spot. In your Test project (f.e. Test.Dataacess) you will have to add an app.config file also with the connectionstring.